# ValueError: shapes (12,2) and (24,) not aligned: 2 (dim 1) != 24 (dim 0)

Tags: python, optimization, scipy

I need to minimize Loss based on two loss variables L1 & L2. So my objective function is

```
z=a*L1+(1-a)*L2,subject to constraint
L2-L1<=G1
```

I have around 1 million rows of records in csv format. Each row contains 1 value of L1,1 of L2 & 1 of G1 & 1 of a. Considering the data size I thought to use Trust region interior point optimization.
To start with it initially I took a small data of 12 rows from my data set & wrote following code.

```
from scipy.optimize import LinearConstraint
from scipy.optimize import minimize
from scipy.optimize import SR1

df=pd.read_csv('subset.csv')

linear_constraint = LinearConstraint([[-1, 1], [-1, 1],[-1, 1],[-1, 1],[-1, 1],[-1, 1],[-1, 1],[-1, 1],[-1, 1],[-1, 1],[-1, 1],[-1, 1]], 
                                     [-np.inf,-np.inf,-np.inf,-np.inf,-np.inf,-np.inf,-np.inf,-np.inf,-np.inf,-np.inf,-np.inf,-np.inf],                                      [0.0313,0.7153,0.1341,0.338,0,0.0182,0.2188,0.3234,0.5558,0,0.1382,0.7191])

L1=df.iloc[:,19].values
L2=df.iloc[:,18].values
x=np.concatenate([L1,L2])
a=df.iloc[:,17]

def loss(x):
    return sum(a*x[0:12]+(1-a)*x[12:24])

def jacobian_const(x):

    L=len(x)
    Lo2=int(L/2)
    def row_i(l,N):
          No2 = int(N/2)
          col_i =[0.0]*N
          col_i[l-1] =-1
          col_i[l-1+No2] = 1
          return col_i
    J = row_i(1,L)
    Jacobian=[]
    Jacobian.append(J)
    type(J)
    for l in range(1,Lo2): 
        Jacobian.append(row_i(2,L))      
    return Jacobian

res = minimize(loss, x, method='trust-constr',jac=jacobian_const,hess=SR1(), 
                constraints=[linear_constraint],
                options={'verbose': 1})
```

After running this code I'm getting error message as

> ValueError: shapes (12,2) and (24,) not aligned: 2 (dim 1) != 24 (dim 0)

Can you suggest me what changes I need to do to eliminate this error?Sorry, I can't able to share the data. It's client data

Comment: Any suggestion please?

Comment: You should start by looking at the traceback to figure out what line of your code produced the `ValueError`. BTW; the problem is unlikely to be due to the actual data, but more likely due to the form of the data, so you should be able to create an MVCE with fake data.

Comment: Hi @MarkDickinson, I'm new to optimizaiton. Can you please suggest me where should I look into? I'm getting this error while running `minimize` function. My Jacobian is  (12,24) matrix

Comment: In Scipy doc https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/optimize.html#trust-region-constrained-algorithm-method-trust-constr, I'm seeing that Jacobian is defined for non linear constraint only.But I have linear constraint for which I defined Jacobian. Is that something which is creating error?

Comment: You need to look at the exception *traceback*. I can't help you with that, because I can't see the traceback. You'd increase the chances of us being able to help if you were to show the traceback, but we really need an MVCE, too.